# Clojure: map function with updatable state

Tags: clojure

What is the best way of implementing map function together with an updatable state between applications of function to each element of sequence? To illustrate the issue let's suppose that we have a following problem:

I have a vector of the numbers. I want a new sequence where each element is multiplied by 2 and then added number of 10's in the sequence up to and including the current element. For example from:

```
[20 30 40 10 20 10 30]
```

I want to generate:

```
[40 60 80 21 41 22 62]
```

Without adding the count of 10 the solution can be formulated using a high level of abstraction:

```
(map #(* 2 %) [20 30 40 10 20 10 30])
```

Having count to update forced me to "go to basic" and the solution I came up with is:

```
(defn my-update-state [x state]
  (if (= x 10) (+ state 1) state)
  )

(defn my-combine-with-state [x state]
  (+ x state))

(defn map-and-update-state [vec fun state update-state combine-with-state]
  (when-not (empty? vec)
    (let [[f & other] vec
          g (fun f)
          new-state (update-state f state)]
      (cons (combine-with-state g new-state) (map-and-update-state other fun new-state update-state combine-with-state))
      )))


(map-and-update-state [20 30 40 50 10 20 10 30 ] #(* 2 %) 0 my-update-state my-combine-with-state )
```

My question: is it the appropriate/canonical way to solve the problem or I overlooked some important concepts/functions.

PS:

1. The original problem is walking AST (abstract syntax tree) and generating new AST together with updating symbol table, so when proposing the solution to the problem above please keep it in mind.
2. I do not worry about blowing up stack, so replacement with loop+recur is not 
   my concern here.
3. Is using global Vars or Refs instead of passing state as an argument a definite no-no?

Comment: Using global mutable state isn't a no-no but it is best avoided. Especially for things like this where you can compose functions. But, Clojure isn't pure so if having refs or atoms improves your code by all means use them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce` to accumulate a pair of the number of 10s seen so far and the current vector of results.:

```
(defn map-update [v]
  (letfn [(update [[ntens v] i]
             (let [ntens (+ ntens (if (= 10 i) 1 0))]
               [ntens (conj v (+ ntens (* 2 i)))]))]
    (second (reduce update [0 []] v))))
```

Comment: Thank you. I should really twist my mind in the functional word to fit my mental picture into reduce function :)  Your approach worked for AST processing.

Answer (score 3):

To count # of 10 you can do

```
(defn count-10[col]
  (reductions + (map #(if (= % 10) 1 0) col)))
```

Example:

```
user=> (count-10 [1 2 10 20 30 10 1])
(0 0 1 1 1 2 2)
```

And then a simple map for the final result

```
(map + col  col (count-10 col)))
```

Comment: You approach works for a simple demonstration problem but i do not see how it can be expanded to AST process without processing the elements twice. Each element in the vector should be processed with the state updated from the previous node and update algorithm can be actually quite complex. In you approach I would need to process the vector twice. The first run is used to generate the sequence of state and the second run to merge this sequence of state together with updating vectors.

Comment: Did you notice any significant performance degradation for processing the vector twice?

Comment: This is (the/an) idiomatic approach. If, in profiling, you find repeating over sequences is where your bottleneck lies then it is time for speedups.

Comment: I did not measure the actual performance and I suspect it will not not be a bottleneck. It just "does not feel right" to do the same thing twice to get an updated state first and then actual result later. I decided to go with "reduce" function mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce and reductions are good ways to traverse a sequence keeping a state. If you feel your code is not clear you can always use recursion with  loop/recur or lazy-seq like this

```
(defn twice-plus-ntens
  ([coll] (twice-plus-ntens coll 0))
  ([coll ntens]
    (lazy-seq
      (when-let [s (seq coll)]
        (let [item (first s)
              new-ntens (if (= 10 item) (inc ntens) ntens)]
          (cons (+ (* 2 item) new-ntens) 
                (twice-plus-ntens (rest s) new-ntens)))))))
```

have a look at map source code evaluating this at your repl

```
(source map)
```

I've skipped chunked optimization and multiple collection support.

You can make it a higher-order function this way

```
(defn map-update
  ([mf uf coll] (map-update mf uf (uf) coll))
  ([mf uf val coll]
    (lazy-seq
      (when-let [s (seq coll)]
        (let [item (first s)
              new-status (uf item val)]
          (cons (mf item new-status) 
                (map-update mf uf new-status (rest s))))))))

(defn update-f
  ([] 0)
  ([item status]
    (if (= item 10) (inc status) status)))

(defn map-f [item status]
  (+ (* 2 item) status))

(map-update map-f update-f in)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate way is to use function with state

```
(into
  []
  (map
    (let [mem (atom 0)]
      (fn [val]
        (when (== val 10) (swap! mem inc))
        (+ @mem (* val 2)))))
  [20 30 40 10 20 10 30])
```

also see

```
memoize
```

standard function